# serving other types of files through jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following works fine if I need to serve the files which are of text types like log files, text files, etc...

But I'm unable to serve word specific files or any pdf/image files.

```
 function ShowFile(strPath){
    if (objHttpFileDataRequest){
        objHttpFileDataRequest.abort();
    }
    objHttpFileDataRequest = $.get(
        "includes/main.cfm",
        {
            path: encodeURI(strPath)
        },
        function(strFileData){
            $("#readerArea pre#filecontent").text(strFileData);
        }
    );
}
var objHttpFileDataRequest = null;
```

I do have relevant code for handling pdf, images, and doctype files on my server, I only know that this jQuery should do something, I think that there is something missing.

Comment: The `$("#readerArea pre#filecontent").text(strFileData);` works for plain text files, not binary files like pdf/images.

Comment: right, so what should i do for other types of files?

Comment: Encode it as base64 before downloading, then use one of these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3665115/519413

Comment: You might find these two links useful, 1:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902299/using-jquery-ajax-to-download-a-binary-file ... 2: https://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: And do note, for a user (client browser) to be able to read/show binary files like a pdf (can be viewed with a javascript library though), it needs to have the proper plug-in installed, which is out of your control.

Comment: i have server code for viewing, i just need it to go through the url once i get the file, i can server it as its type

Comment: "Server code for viewing" won't work client side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the extension (From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042353/1410567)
2. If it's txt or log files (or, add other files), show the plain text output

*else*

3. If it's not plain text as delineated above, redirect the browser (or open new window) to the file:

```js
 function ShowFile(strPath){
    if (objHttpFileDataRequest){
        objHttpFileDataRequest.abort();
    }
    objHttpFileDataRequest = $.get("includes/main.cfm",
    {
        path: encodeURI(strPath)
    },
    function(strFileData){
        openFile(strFileData); //assuming strFileData is a string with a URI path
    });
}

var objHttpFileDataRequest = null;

function openFile(file) {
    var extension = file.substr( (file.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
    switch(extension) {
        case 'txt':
        case 'log':
            $("#readerArea pre#filecontent").text(strFileData);
        break;     

        default:
            window.open(strFileData, "_blank");  //is not plain text, open in new window - this may be blocked by pop-up blocker protection in some browsers
    }
};
```